# Polling with webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm currently trying to improve my skills with webpack to enhance my project automation and build phases.

I'm trying to up a project on **webpack-dev-server**, I tried to analyze the different options available but i can't figure what is **poll** under **watchOptions**...

I also tried to search on the web but i don't completely get what it is.

If you may explain me please.

Comment: It's the milliseconds that pass between two checks for changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can use poll when using some Virtual Machine mechanism like Docker in order to make work watch.

Here you have more information: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptions-poll